# Difference between 3D-tensor and 4D-tensor for images input of DL Keras framework

Tags: python, image, keras, shapes, tensor

By convention an image tensor is always 3D : One dimension for its `height`, one for its `width` and a third one for its `color channel`. Its shape looks like `(height, width, color)`.

For instance a batch of 128 color images of size 256x256 could be stored in a 4D-tensor of shape `(128, 256, 256, 3)`. The color channel represents here RGB colors. Another example with batch of 128 grayscale images stored in a 4D-tensor of shape `(128, 256, 256, 1)`. The color could be coded as 8-bit integers.

For the second example, the last dimension is a vector containing only one element. It is then possible to use a 3D-tensor of shape `(128, 256, 256,)` instead.

Here comes my question : I would like to know if there is a difference between using a 3D-tensor rather than a 4D-tensor as the training input of a deep-learning framework using keras.

EDIT : My input layer is a conv2D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I you take a look at the Keras documentation of the `conv2D` layer [here](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) you will see that the shape of the input tensor *must* be 4D.

> **conv2D layer input shape**
>   4D tensor with shape: `(batch, channels, rows, cols)` if `data_format` is "channels_first" or 4D tensor with shape: `(batch, rows, cols, channels)` if `data_format` is "channels_last".

So the 4th dimension of the shape is mandatory, even if it is only "1" as for a grayscaled image.
So in fact, it is not a matter of performance gain nor lack of simplicity, it's only the mandatory input argument's shape.
Hope it answers your question.